# Need to refresh page when going from portrait to landscape css Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, page-refresh, landscape-portrait

I have a site that when it appears on a small smart phone (portrait) the logo is by far too big and I want to swap it for a smaller image.

I can do it no problem and feel very intelligentish BUT but when the punter holds the phone landscape it returns to the large image, I am happy wth this but when the punter then holds the phone portrait the bigger image is still there until the page is refreshed.

What can I do to have it so as the punter does not need to refresh the page after turning phone from landscape to portrait.

I attach my current snippet below. It is from a .css page. please note I have also tried adding this snippet to the first few lines of code in the .css page and it didn't make a difference. The image replacement is only about 10kb

/* +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- */

```
/* Samsung Galaxy S2 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation :     portrait) {

.phonenum {
display: none; 
}
.two-column-column1 .hide-logo {
display: none !important;
}
.two-column-column1 {
width:274px; /*width of my new small image image*/
height:74px; /*height of my new small image image*/
background: url(images/londonfabriccompany274-74.png) no-repeat;
margin:0; /* I didn't want no margin */
padding:0; /* I didn't want padding either */
}
.inner-one-columns-wrapper {
margin-top: 6px;
}
}

/* +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- */
```

thanks for your input cheers

Seemore Yea Baby

Comment: I have tried 
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
and it didnt work. please note I am using an S2 and have also tried 
    atmedia only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 533px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (orientation: landscape) but that was of no use.
sorry for not responding earlier but i was trying to work out as to how to reply directlly to your q and couldnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a landscape parameter to your media query and setting the same image requirements around that media query?

/* Samsung Galaxy S2 (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation :     portrait) {

/** Your parameters go here **/
}

Then:

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){

/** Your parameters go here **/

}